# one element is clicked then other same click event was performed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Html Code : `<span><i style="cursor: pointer;" id="saveProd" class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>`

Here, id="saveProd" one icon will clicked. Then Run These **Jquery**.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#qv1").click(function(e){
        //alert("qv1");
        //$("#saveProd").attr({"id":"save1"});
        $("#qvimage").attr({"src":"img/product/1.jpg"});    
        $("#qvbname").html("Luceat Pro");
        $("#qvpname").html("SELECTED Black Denim Jacket");
        $("#qvprice").html("5,900.00 &euro;");
        $("#qvdis").html("&nbsp;");
        $("#qvoff").html("Offers : ");

        $("#saveProd").click(function(e){
            $("#saveProd").removeClass("fa-heart-o").addClass("fa-heart");
            $.localStorage("p1","product1");
        });
        value = $.localStorage('p1');
        if(value == "product1"){
            //alert(value);
            $("#saveProd").removeClass("fa-heart-o").addClass("fa-heart");
        }
        else {
            $("#saveProd").removeClass("fa-heart").addClass("fa-heart-o");
        }

        /*$(".close").click(function(e){
            $("#save1").attr({"id":"saveProd"});
            //console.log("Id Changed to saveProd");
        });*/
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#qv2").click(function(e){
        $("#qvimage").attr({"src":"img/product/2.jpg"});    
        $("#qvbname").html("Luceat Pro");
        $("#qvpname").html("Black Solid Jacket");
        $("#qvprice").html("<s style='color: grey; font-size: 12px;'>4,500.00 &nbsp;&euro;</s>&nbsp;2,250.00&nbsp;&euro;");
        $("#qvdis").html("&nbsp;(50% Off)");
        $("#qvoff").html("Offers : Get 50% Off");

        $("#saveProd").click(function(e){
            $("#saveProd").removeClass("fa-heart-o").addClass("fa-heart");
            $.localStorage("p2","product2");
        });
        value = $.localStorage('p2');
        if(value == "product2"){
            //alert(value);
            $("#saveProd").removeClass("fa-heart-o").addClass("fa-heart");
        }
        else {
            $("#saveProd").removeClass("fa-heart").addClass("fa-heart-o");  
        }
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#qv3").click(function(e){
        $("#qvimage").attr({"src":"img/product/3.jpg"});    
        $("#qvbname").html("Luceat Exlusive");
        $("#qvpname").html("Solid Brown Lether Jacket");
        $("#qvprice").html("<s style='color: grey; font-size: 12px;'>1,000.00 &nbsp;&euro;</s>&nbsp;500.00&nbsp;&euro;");
        $("#qvdis").html("&nbsp;(50% Off)");
        $("#qvoff").html("Offers : Get 50% Off");

        $("#saveProd").click(function(e){
            $("#saveProd").removeClass("fa-heart-o").addClass("fa-heart");
            $.localStorage("p3","product3");
        });
        value = $.localStorage('p3');
        if(value == "product3"){
            //alert(value);
            $("#saveProd").removeClass("fa-heart-o").addClass("fa-heart");
        }
        else {
            $("#saveProd").removeClass("fa-heart").addClass("fa-heart-o");
        }
    });
});
```

here, First Click #qv1 then performed some Of actions and then click the #saveProd id then Performe the Store in local. But There is a Problem When Click #qv3 And click #saveProd then Store 3 Values Like Product1,Product2,Product3.

Any Solution ?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Every time you click one of your `#qv...` elements, you add another click handler to `#saveProd`.  How many different click handlers does that same element really need?  You should really just assign *one* click handler to that element when the page loads and, inside of that handler, conditionally determine the logic of whatever you're trying to do.  Dynamically adding more and more click handlers like this means that, before long, clicking that button is going to be doing *a lot* of things.

Comment: yes I will need. but any other way can do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *problem* is that you keep assigning more and more event handlers to your `#saveProd` element.  In every other click handler, you assign another click handler to that one.  So each time a `#qvX` element is clicked, `#saveProd` does more and more things.

A *quick and dirty* fix would be to *remove* event handlers before assigning new ones.  First, change all of your `.click()` handler assignments to `.on()` handler assignments.  Something like this:

```
$("#saveProd").on('click', function(e){
    //...
});
```

Do this for each of your `#saveProd` click handlers.  Then, before each one, use a call to [`.off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove any click handlers:

```
$("#saveProd").off('click');
$("#saveProd").on('click', function(e){
    //...
});
```

Again, this is the *quick and dirty* fix.  (That is, it should get your code "working" with the least changes.)  Ideally you wouldn't need to keep un-assigning and re-assigning click handlers.  Instead, assign a *single* click handler when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#qv1").on('click', function(e){
    //...
  });

  $("#qv2").on('click', function(e){
    //...
  });

  $("#qv3").on('click', function(e){
    //...
  });

  $("#saveProd").on('click', function(e){
    //...
  });

});
```

Then if that click handler for `#saveProd` needs to *conditionally* perform different logic depending on the state of the page, perform those conditional checks inside that one click handler.

Which *itself* isn't ideal either, to have a function conditionally do different things, but it's at least a step toward a better design in this case.  From there you could refactor further, or perhaps even remove the need for conditions entirely.  After all, most of this code is *highly* repeated and does *very* similar things.  A little refactoring could go a long way with your code.  Starting with... Is it even such a terrible thing to store all three values in local storage every time, even if one or two of them are unnecessary placeholder defaults?  Probably not.

Comment: Thank You..! This Solution Work for me..